# Как сделать поиск, как в OperaMini?

Tags: android, java

Как сделать такой же поиск, как в Opera Mini? По нажатии она растягивается, при нажатии Enter она что-то делает, а при вводе текст просто двигается, а EditText не растягивается.

Вот моя картинка:

И код по перехвату Enter, но Enter не перехватывается...

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    if (event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: @xTIGRx, час назад это был другой вопрос. Зачем вы изменили заголовок и текст вопроса?

Comment: @xTIGRx я Андроид-разработкой занимаюсь уже 3 года, и совершенно не согласен с тем, что делают больше багов. У вас, видимо, код состоит целиком из костылей. И костыли, деййствительно, иногда с выходом новой версии перестают работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:lines="1"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: Ну что неужели ни кто не знает?( (

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что надо было в `InputType` выбрать `AutoCorrect`.